# Why use (__weak Class) in a function definition in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a factory class that builds UITableViewCell of different types that I have defined, let's call they: TypeATableViewCell and TypeBTableViewCell.

Now the method in my factory class is defined as follow:

`+ (UITableViewCell*)getCellForIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier cellClass:(__weak Class)cellClass;`

Why would someone choose to use (__weak Class) here instead of just (Class).

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, this won't matter. `Class`es are effectively interned -- once registered with the runtime, AFAICT, they can never be unregistered, so the runtime will always be "retaining" them (such that it is). Stepping through the assembly shows that `+[NSObject retain]` is a no-op (just returns self, and does nothing else). However, if you create a new root class and try to retain it, like this...

```
Class foo = objc_allocateClassPair(nil, "Foo", 0);
[foo retain];
```

... the runtime will barf, because the new root class doesn't implement `retain` meaning that if you wanted your API to tolerate new root classes that don't implement `retain` you would have to mark their uses as `__weak` so that ARC didn't call `retain` on them. So I guess, *technically* you would **always** want variables of type `Class` to be weak, but in practice it's unlikely to ever matter, since anything you would be using as a table cell class would have to inherit from `UITableViewCell` anyway (which inherits from `NSObject`.)

PS: Just stepped through it and `NSProxy` is the same as `NSObject` in this regard. Appears to just return `self` and do nothing else. So unless you're off creating new root classes, you're probably safe skipping the `__weak` qualifier.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, what's the use case for creating a root class instead of inheriting from NSObject? Also, if I used (Class) instead, at what point exactly would the retain method be called? I guess I'm unclear why it would need to be called in the first place.

Comment: The use case for creating a new root class is that the developer is exceedingly "clever". I've never heard a convincing argument for it. (i.e. something that couldn't be more idiomatically achieved inheriting from NSObject or NSProxy) As for the calls to retain, AFAIK it's not explicitly specified, only that ARC will, as necessary, insert calls to retain/release/autorelease into your code. One can imagine that it might retain something on method call boundaries. But I haven't investigated enough to know in detail. I would guess that you could read the clang sources to learn more.

Comment: @ipmcc great answer, +1, just curiosity: Can you please cite a scenario where a programmer get "exceedingly clever" that he wants/needs to create his own new root class in an objective c/iOS sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, the argument is, "I explicitly don't want any of the stuff that comes with `NSObject` or `NSProxy`" but that argument is basically BS because ObjC doesn't have `final` methods, and all instance and class methods are `virtual`, meaning you can override *anything* that `NSObject` and `NSProxy` implements by default (including `isKindOfClass:` etc.) I invite anyone who disagrees to post a compelling argument -- I'm ripe for the convincing -- but it's gonna be a tall order.